Noise density in 1/f region
The datasheet of the ADR1000 voltage reference specifies the 1/f noise density as 30nV/sqrt(Hz) at 10Hz and 300nV/sqrt(Hz) at 0.1Hz.
Given that this is the 1/f region of the voltage reference, how can we calculate the total noise in the frequency band from 0.1Hz to 10Hz? (Which is the usual noise specification)


how can we calculate the total noise in the frequency band from 0.1Hz
to 10Hz?

It's stated in the data sheet as 0.9 µV p-p so maybe just use that figure or the graph: -


How many $\sigma$ in p-p?

Thanks, so simple

@JohnDoty your comment is irrelevant because the number came from the data sheet.

@Andyaka P-p isn't noise density. Mathematically, p-p is infinite. On a scope, 6 sigma is a rough guess. Of course if that's what you want, p-p is fine.

@JohnDoty I'm sorry but the question asked for total noise and not noise density. Clearly, the OP didn't see the value and just needed a little helping hand to find out what the usually specified value is. Are you trying to conflate the question? Stick to the question asked is my strong advice.

My mistake. However, p-p is not the same thing as noise power, which is what I'd want to use for "total noise". See @Colin's answer.

Even as "total noise", i.e. integrated noise over a bandwidth of interest, p-p is not really a rigorous number. RMS would be better (IMO)

@tobalt why not contact Analog devices and tell them? In fact, why not contact TI and Microchip as well and tell them that the vast majority of their op-amp specifications are also lacking.

I think they know... Newer datasheets tend to mention RMS. For a good SE answer, one could attempt to educate that part, as per the comments of @JohnDoty

@tobalt it wouldn't help because the AD part data sheet is full of holes i.e. the graphs of noise don't match the typical figures etc.. Hence any attempt to try and figure this out theoretically will be wasted.

Ok too bad. Anyway in case it helps any of the readers, I recall very very tentatively that Vpp = 6x Vrms was a usual figure for these noise figures. But I also believe that these numbers are just totally arbitrary and that the test engi just filled whatever they read on the test fixture without spending any second thought... Or they are just guesses anyways

@tobalt https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/281004/20218 <-- this explain why 6 or 6.6 is used (stats)

Andy mentioned what was said in the datasheet.
But generally speaking, there's unfortunately no easy formula for calculating the total noise but there are some "safe" methods of estimation by utilizing worst case scenario.
Analog Devices has a white paper on this.

Picture from their document MT-048 Tutorial: Op Amp Noise Relationships: 1/f Noise, RMS Noise, and Equivalent Noise. Caution: clicking on the link will automatically download the PDF file to the document.
And just a side note, if you're curious about measuring voltage noise across a resistance:
Vn = sqrt(4kRT*(FH–FL))
This is known as the Johnson-Nyquist noise voltage.

Didn't know that 1/f looked like a line in a lin-log-plot, or that Vpp=6.6* Vrms was a universal relationship..  Cringe is strong when you see someone trying to write a rigorous App Note on noise analysis and then put forth such an analysis when they could have just said: square the amplitude noise density spectrum, integrate and take square root. The 6.6 referring to the 0.1%ile noise should be added to your answer to explain the otherwise arbitrary picture.

There are already correct answers from Andy and Colin here, but I want to add some more background because 1/f noise is a sensitive topic for me personally 
Some usual numbers that are commonly used to express noise are not infact rigorous. So I will mention these and then lead over to actually rigorous numbers that you should rely on instead if you can get hold of them.

Vp-p is only rigorous when the bandwidth is given and when the peak percentile is given. 0.1 Hz - 10 Hz is not a rigorous bandwidth spec, when the rolloff is not specified. Therefore Vp-p is not advisable to spec 1/f noise.

By extension from 1., Vrms in 0.1-10 Hz is also not advisable. Though it does away with the unknown peak percentile, it still has the issue of the bandwidth spec.

Slightly better is Vrms per frequency decade. This number is typically taken as an integral from the 1/f range of the spectrum, i.e. you can also calculate it yourself if you have a spectrum. Square the spectrum, integrate one frequency decade, and take the square root. The number is pretty rigorous and should be close to 1/sqrt(2) times the Vrms of 0.1-10 Hz.

A very rigorous number is the spectral coefficient of the 1/f slope, i.e. it is the point where the 1/f slope crosses 1 Hz. This is not a rms number but just a number of Volts. This number gives a good estimate of how stable the voltage reference is.

The ultimate number in terms of the stability of a voltage reference is its Allan deviation. The floor of the Allan deviation vs. time plot will be limited by 1/f noise for voltage references. This floor of the Allan deviation has a rigorous relation with the spectral coefficient in bullet 4.: It is sqrt(2 ln 2) times the coefficient of the 1/f slope. This is again a number in Volts, the base precision of the voltage reference, a figure that metrologists use to compare voltage standards.


If you are doing anything precision related, try to get at least to bullet 3 of this list.

I‘m familiar up to bullet 4., but bullet 5. is new to me. Thanks for that!
